C++ sigbus error when trying to catch an exception
I have come across an interesting case, where C++ gives me a bus error, when I am trying to catch an exception.
I created a minimal example to reproduce the error:
#include <iostream>

using Vertex = std::vector<double>;

struct TestStruct {
    std::vector<Vertex> vertices;
};

void testFunction(TestStruct& set1, TestStruct& set2) {
    if (set1.vertices.front().size() != set2.vertices.front().size()) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("set1 has different dimensions (" +
                                    std::to_string(set1.vertices.front().size()) + ") than set2 (" +
                                    std::to_string(set2.vertices.front().size()) + ").");
    }
}

int main() {
    TestStruct set1;
    TestStruct set2;

    std::vector<Vertex> vertices1 = {{0.0, 0.0}};
    std::vector<Vertex> vertices2 = {{0.0, 0.0, 0.0}};

    set1.vertices = vertices1;
    set2.vertices = vertices2;

    try {
        testFunction(set1, set2);
    } catch (const std::invalid_argument& e) {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}

What I would expect here is that the code cathces the invalid_argument error and prints it.
However, the actual output I get is:
Process finished with exit code 138 (interrupted by signal 10:SIGBUS)
The stack trace is
Process 7078 launched: '/Users/roland/Development/cps/sonia/build-debug/examples/cpp/Debug/sonia_exe' (arm64)
Process 7078 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=261, address=0xdac11410)
    frame #0: 0x000000018d12aa58 libunwind.dylib`_Unwind_GetIP + 224
libunwind.dylib`:
->  0x18d12aa58 <+224>: autib  x16, x0
    0x18d12aa5c <+228>: mov    x17, x16
    0x18d12aa60 <+232>: xpaci  x17
    0x18d12aa64 <+236>: cmp    x16, x17
Target 1: (sonia_exe) stopped.
(lldb) bt
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=261, address=0xdac11410)
  * frame #0: 0x000000018d12aa58 libunwind.dylib`_Unwind_GetIP + 224
    frame #1: 0x0000000180887c7c libc++abi.dylib`__gxx_personality_v0 + 588
    frame #2: 0x0000000100494930 libunwind.1.dylib`unwind_phase2 + 388
    frame #3: 0x0000000100494b68 libunwind.1.dylib`_Unwind_Resume + 100
    frame #4: 0x0000000100005ad4 sonia_exe`testFunction(set1=0x000000016fdfef20, set2=0x000000016fdfef08) at sonia.cpp:21:9
    frame #5: 0x00000001000061e8 sonia_exe`main at sonia.cpp:38:9
    frame #6: 0x000000018054d0e0 dyld`start + 2360
(lldb) 


Interestingly, when I don't try to catch the error, the code throws the error as expected.
I really have no clue what is going on here, and would appreciate any help!
Follow-up
Ok here is a follow-up from my side.
First of all, thank you to everyone who tried to reproduce the error!
Since people were not able to reproduce it, I tested the code with all the different compilers and different architectures I had installed on my system. This time also in a clean structure.
TLDR: I only managed to reproduce the issue with llvm (version 18.1.8 arm64).
Here are all the results

arm64 llvm (version 18.1.8)

zsh: bus error  ./build_arm_llvm/example

Stack trace:
(lldb) run
Process 16227 launched: '/Users/roland/Development/personal/minimal_example/build_arm_llvm/example' (arm64)
Process 16227 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=261, address=0xdac11410)
    frame #0: 0x000000018d12aa58 libunwind.dylib`_Unwind_GetIP + 224
libunwind.dylib`:
->  0x18d12aa58 <+224>: autib  x16, x0
    0x18d12aa5c <+228>: mov    x17, x16
    0x18d12aa60 <+232>: xpaci  x17
    0x18d12aa64 <+236>: cmp    x16, x17
Target 0: (example) stopped.
(lldb) bt
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=261, address=0xdac11410)
  * frame #0: 0x000000018d12aa58 libunwind.dylib`_Unwind_GetIP + 224
    frame #1: 0x0000000180887c7c libc++abi.dylib`__gxx_personality_v0 + 588
    frame #2: 0x0000000100484930 libunwind.1.dylib`unwind_phase2 + 388
    frame #3: 0x0000000100484b68 libunwind.1.dylib`_Unwind_Resume + 100
    frame #4: 0x0000000100001ca4 example`testFunction(TestStruct&, TestStruct&) + 544
    frame #5: 0x0000000100001f80 example`main + 416
    frame #6: 0x000000018054d0e0 dyld`start + 2360


arm64 gcc (version 14.1.0) --> works as expected

Output:
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
  what():  set1 has different dimensions (2) than set2 (3).
zsh: abort      ./build_arm_g++/example


arm64 apple clang (version 15.0.0) --> works as expected

Output:
Exception: set1 has different dimensions (2) than set2 (3).


x86 gcc (version 13.2.0) --> works as expected

Output:
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
  what():  set1 has different dimensions (2) than set2 (3).
zsh: abort      ./build_x86_gcc/example


x86 apple clang (version 15.0.0) --> works as expected

Output:
Exception: set1 has different dimensions (2) than set2 (3).

Do you think this could be a bug in the specific llvm compiler?

https://godbolt.org/z/WGzoEd3bY Cannot reproduce.

It works fine for me on Windows PC, the output I see is: Exception: set1 has different dimensions (2) than set2 (3)..

One thing that could potentially be wrong is calling front() on empty container. But it's not the case in your example.

This doesn't seem to be the minimum reproducible sample code. There's some kind of UB in the refactored(invisible) part of your code. Most probable case is a buffer overrun that corrupts exception handling mechanism.

Ok that's fair, I executed the code in the structure of an existing project, because I did not want to lose more time on the problem then I already have. However, since people cannot reproduce it, I will do some more tests in a clean structure.

its rather the opposite, not executing the code you show here = loosing more time. UB in code can cause weird effects, in particular it can make code to effect other code even when it seems impossible.

Just imagine what would happen if vertices1 is set to {}. It crashes.

sonia.cpp:38 the code provided does not have a line 38.  The EXC_BAD_ACCESS displayed is not from the code provided.

It is. I just removed the commented out lines. As previously stated, I executed the code in an existing project structure. See my follow-up answer for more details.
